# Returning success message from JSON post

Tags: c#, json, angular2-forms

I have the following to post JSON to a C# Web API:

```
submitForm(data: any): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.post(
        'https://localhost:44396/api/PostNewComputer/AddItem/?=', data,
        { headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }) }).subscribe(data => { return "test"; });
}
```

And the API controller:

```
public class PostNewComputerController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult AddItem(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {

            //var dynamicObject = Json.Decode(jsonString);
            var jsonString = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();

            string message;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source = MYSERVER; initial catalog = AssetDB; integrated security = SSPI; persist security info = True; Trusted_Connection = Yes"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("POST_NEW_COMPUTER", con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@JSON_TEXT", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = jsonString;

                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        con.Close();

                        message = "Item Successfully Added";
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //throw e;
                        message = e.Message;
                    }

                }

                return Ok(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to create a response message from the POST call that is then fed back to the webpage when the user submits the form to show that the post has worked.

However, this current setup doesn't work and I am struggling to solves this.

Is there a correct way to do this properly?

Comment: What do you mean the current setup doesn't work? Are you getting an error? Does the build succeed?

Comment: The build succeeds, but I can't get the Observable to return the message.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpResponseMessage` to post back message as:

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(string))]
public HttpResponseMessage AddItem(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    string message = string.Empty;

    try 
    {
        .....

        message = "Item Successfully Added";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        .....

        message = e.Message;
    }

    response = Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, message);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Thats great but how would the message be returned in Angular 2?

Comment: See the edit to my answer.  `response` object which is returned here contains the message in the angular 2 response.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Angular service. Your API is correct

You're trying to `subscribe` to the response from your API before mapping it back to `json()`, you need to do the following, see below:

Firstly this is what should be in your component:

```
submitForm(data: any): Observable<Response> {
  //this url can't be correct?
  let url:string = 'https://localhost:44396/api/PostNewComputer/AddItem/?=';

  return this.http.post(url, data, this._headers())
    .map((res:Response) => res.json());
}

//Created a method to do the headers for you
private _headers():RequestOptionsArgs {   
  let headers:Headers = new headers();    
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  let options:RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions();
  options.headers = headers;

  return options;
}
```

You would then call your service from your component as follows:

```
public functionName():void {
  this.service.submitForm(data)
    .subscribe((res:any) => {
      //this will contain your response
    },
    (error:any) => {
      //this will contain your error
    });
}
```

You need to ensure the model you're posting matches the model expected. With regards to the URL you are posting to, that seems incorrect, is it not `https://localhost:44396/api/PostNewComputer/AddItem/`?